# Screen turns off when lid is closed

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I have an ASUS ROG G701VI, and in my power settings I've already changed it so that when the lid is closed the display should do nothing. However when I do close the lid (or even leave it open a few inches) the display still turns off. Upon opening it again, the display refreshes and flickers before turning back on completely.

I want to use Chrome remote desktop with this laptop with the lid closed, but with the display turning off I can't do anything.

How might I be able to prevent the display from turning off when the lid is closed?

Comment: Remote desktop should not be influenced by the local screen being dark. Screen displaying and the OS working are independant.

Comment: The problem is that when the local display is off I can still move the mouse but am unable to do anything else remotely. Upon opening the lid again, both refresh and then I am able to interact with the desktop.

Comment: Most laptops have a hardware switch that at very least controls the backlight, and more often controls all output to the screen. This switch operates independent of the OS or BIOS, and simply cuts the output. Remote desktop not working while the screen is off is most likely a different issue that is related, but should not be. As in, you should be able to Remote Desktop while the lid is closed just fine, and the problem isn't that the screen turns off, but that Remote Desktop isn't behaving as it ought.

Comment: This is my experience as well. If the lid is open, I can use it. If I close the lid, the chrome remote desktop goes black (does not disconnect).

Answer (score 0):

At least one other possibility is that there is a BIOS setting that controls it. Based on a quick look at page 70 of the [manual](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-G701VI-7th-Gen-Intel-Core/HelpDesk_Manual/), it appears there is at least a "Wake On Lid Open" setting that is Enabled by default. You could try turning that off, or maybe if you hit F7 or poke around further, there are more settings that would cover the lid close case.

In case anyone reading this doesn't know, to get into BIOS setup, you generally press F2 soon after powering on the machine. (Checked that this is true for this machine.)

Comment: I've disabled that setting in the BIOS setup, but the problem persists. Is there another place where I might be able to see BIOS settings? That particular setting is the only one concerning the lid in the BIOS setup specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent your screen from turning off, nor that you should.
The real issue here is probably that your notebook is disconnecting from the network when the lid is closed.
And this could be caused by a "feature" in your network adapter's driver.

I was affected by just the same issue on a new laptop, I couldn't Remote Desktop to it as soon as the lid was closed, while Windows was set up not to do anything on closing the lid.

Disabling the "Ultra Low Power Mode" setting in my network adapter's driver settings fixed this (I219-LM adapter).
Try this maybe.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.